# How to merge contents of multiple folders?

Tags: file-management, merge

How can I merge the contents of multiple folders into one?

I have 50 folders having 1 file each. I want to create only 1 folder containing 50 files without using the lengthy method of cut, copy and paste.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Windows, and these 50 folders are all subfolders of the same parent folder, you can use the Find function in Windows Explorer to get a list of all files in those subfolders. Select them and copy/paste is needed only once. No 3rd party tools are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

So, Coming to the solution I would suggest you to download a freeware for Windows (I guess you are using windows) It's name is **Folder Merger** Go google it !.It's a safe and secure trusted software . [Click here to know more about it](http://folder-merger.findmysoft.com/)

Regards

Comment: As it stands, this answer is borderline spam. You can make it far less spam-like by describing *how* OP can use the tool you suggest to accomplish the task asked about.

Comment: Oh .. Thank you Michael I am surely going to do this :)

Comment: I found that Folder Merger tool as it claims it merges the contents of the files from various folders, but it doesn't merge the contents of the files, you can choose to create separate copies. Still a useful tool for me, not sure whether for the original problem requested. The link to the software from the author is https://2xdsoft.de.tl/Folder-Merger.htm